# sql queries between three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Working on Android SMS notification using sqlite.

Got three tables named

```
people: `id`, `people_name` 
info: `id`,`info_name`
people_info: `auto-increment id`, 
      `people_id` <- foreign key (people.id)
      `info_id` <- foreign key (info.id)
```

When people are notified of the info the `people_info` adds the two ids. How to make the WHERE clause to check people is informed; how to filter people who are fully notified and prevent notification redundancy.

Comment: can you add sample data set it will help to undersatnd

Comment: check out the sample table image? with few sample data

Comment: can you attached it to question

Comment: @Aelaf Data and code should never be included in a question as images.  Copy/paste your data as text, so that people trying to answer have actual data to work with.  Using an image is likely to get your question downvoted, and will keep some people from participating in providing an answer.  You can click the `edit` link below the question (directly above the comments) to add the information directly into your question.

Comment: Thank you Sir! will keep that in mind, but how do i add a table with data in the question?

Answer (score 1):

To get rows from `people` where there isn't a row related to that `people` and a particular row in `info`, you can use an *anti-join* pattern.

For example:

```
SELECT p.id           AS `person_id`
     , p.people_name  AS `person_name`
  FROM people p
  LEFT
  JOIN people_info i
    ON i.people_id = p.id
   AND i.info_id =  ?
 WHERE i.people_id IS NULL
 ORDER BY p.id
```

This isn't the only query pattern that returns this result. There are a couple of others, for example, using a NOT EXISTS and correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.id           AS `person_id`
     , p.people_name  AS `person_name`
  FROM people p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                      FROM people_info i
                     WHERE i.people_id = p.id
                       AND i.info_id =  ?
                  )
 ORDER BY p.id
```

---

If you want to return all `(people,info)` tuples that aren't related, rather than a just a single `info`, that can be achieved as well. The specification provided is ambiguous about what value(s) are going to be provided, and an example of the expected output. The answer above addresses only one of several  possible interpretations.

If we want to involve all three tables... to get all info for all people who have not yet been notified, we can use an *anti-join* pattern:

```
SELECT p.id           AS `person_id`
     , p.people_name  AS `person_name`
     , i.id           AS `info_id`
     , i.info_name    AS `info_name`
  FROM people p
 CROSS
  JOIN info i 
  LEFT
  JOIN people_info n
    ON n.people_id = p.id
   AND n.info_id =  i.id
 WHERE n.people_id IS NULL
 ORDER BY p.id, i.id
```

Comment: good Heavens! i sure will ponder over your sql wisdom. Great thanks well before i test your code advice;-)

Comment: THANK YOU A LOT!!! just one last question i want to retrieve further into distinct info with non repeating info (`i.id`), tried  `DISTINCT`. keyword, not working.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` keyword (following the `SELECT` keyword) applies to *all* expressions in the select list. If you only want rows from `info` where at least one `people` hasn't been notified, that query can be written differently. But to modify the example queries above, you could remove all references to `p.` columns from SELECT list (that is, return only `i.` columns), and then add the DISTINCT keyword. But there are better ways to get the result you're after. Without example of the expected resultset, the specification is ambiguous, and we're kinda just guessing what you are trying to achieve.